# I'm not able to run protractor test in firefox but in chrome it runs fine

Tags: protractor

When I am trying to run Protractor e2e test in firefox, it launches the browser but my test scripts do not get executed.

I am using windows Server 2012 R2 machine with firefox version 46.0.1 and Selenium 2.53.0.

It gives me the following error:

```
Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

code\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:89
          Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
          ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:58798/hub
```

I tried running Selenium standalone

```
    code\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\selenium>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
    09:37:21.214 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
    09:37:21.285 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.91-b14
    09:37:21.285 INFO - OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
    09:37:21.293 INFO - v2.53.0, with Core v2.53.0. Built from revision 35ae25b
    09:37:21.332 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
    09:37:21.332 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
    09:37:21.336 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
    registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN8
    09:37:21.336 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
    09:37:21.336 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
09:37:21.434 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
09:37:21.434 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

I am using `npm run e2e` command to execute my test

my Config file:

```
exports.config = {

  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,

  suites: {
      test Suit: 'e2e/TestSuites/Tests/*.js',
  },

   multiCapabilities: [

    // We will want to eventually include the following options to split out tests to multiple instances

    {'browserName': 'firefox'}
  ],


  // only for firefox and chrome - IE will require using a selenium server

  directConnect : true,  

  // make sure that the baseURL reflects the configuration of the web server

  baseUrl: 'http://10.26.5.13:8000/',


  framework: 'jasmine2',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },


  onPrepare: function() {     
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

    return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {

      var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;


      var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
             consolidateAll: true,
             savePath: 'tests/test-results',
             // this will produce distinct xml files for each capability
             filePrefix: browserName + '-xmloutput',
             modifySuiteName: function(generatedSuiteName, suite) {
                 // this will produce distinct suite names for each capability,
                 // e.g. 'firefox.login tests' and 'chrome.login tests'
                 return browserName + '.' + generatedSuiteName;
             }

         });
         jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    });    

  }, 

  resultJsonOutputFile: 'tests/test-results/output.json'

};
```

Comment: is it because selenium standalone is running  http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub and protractor is searching WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:58798/hub

Comment: if that so how can I update WebDriver server location in Protractor

Comment: My config file :  
  multiCapabilities: [

   
   {'browserName': 'firefox'}, 
   // {'browserName': 'chrome'}
  ],
     
  directConnect : true,

Comment: If you are using `directConnect` you shouldn't be hitting the selenium server at all. Are you sure your config is being picked up properly? Can you edit your question and include your entire configuration file and the command you are using to start protractor?

Comment: @NickTomlin Included my Config file.

Comment: What does npm run e2e actually do?

Comment: @NickTomlin it actually runs `protractor tests/protractor-conf.js` command which is defined in  package.json file  ("e2e": "protractor tests/protractor-conf.js",)

Comment: any idea on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this link: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3182,

I was also facing similar issue.

I tried installing Firefox v44.0.2 and then executed my scripts, it worked.

I was using Firefox v46 earlier, and my scripts  were not executing with Firefox v46.

Comment: If you encounter this issue in 2016, try updating firefox to the latest, precesily to v47.0.1 and your protractor tests should run again; no need to go to an older versions as of today :)

Comment: hi @pelican I have tried using Firefox v47.0.1, it launches the browser but my scripts will not execute. I get follwoing errors:    `C:\Local_E2E\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:89
          Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
          ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:64870/hub
    at Error (native)
    at onResponse (C:\Local_E2E\analytics-k\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:89:11)`

Comment: You might need to update your webdriver server jar and chrome driver with this command "webdriver-manager update" - yours might be an older version. Also check this link showcasing the same problem you have and various solutions: "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/276". Lastly, generally just google the error you get you might be surprised that someone else ran into that same problem and posted the question somewhere online.

Comment: Thanks @pelican this Helped, I updated my protractor version to 4.0.2 and my test Ran on Firefox latest version. I was using old protractor version.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with firefox version 49.0.2 and Selenium 2.52.0
I installed Firefox portable 46 and everything worked for me.

And in my protractor.config-file i set:

```
...
    capabilities: {
    // FIREFOX portable in version 46.0.1
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    "firefox_binary": "C:/DEV/FirefoxPortable64-46.0.1/FirefoxPortable64/FirefoxPortable.exe",
    "binary_": "C:/DEV/FirefoxPortable64-46.0.1/FirefoxPortable64/FirefoxPortable.exe"
},
// tells protractor to directly connect to the webdriver
directConnect: true
...
```

I downloaded Firefox Portable here: http://www.m64.info/index.php/firefox-64-bit-portable 
That's also a good opportunity to have more than one version of firefox "installed" :-)
Hope somebody will help it!

Answer (score 1):

Follow Protractor setup here:
http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial#setup

These versions are what worked for me:

```
Node: v6.9.4
NPM: v3.10.10
Protractor: v5.1.0
Selenium WebDriver: 3.0.1
Firefox: 51.0.1
```

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  // no need for seleniumAddress for firefox and chrome
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    firefoxPath: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
  },
  directConnect: true // for firefox and chrome
}
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Answer (score 1):

Add the binary (firefox.exe) location  as moz:firefoxOptions capability

```
exports.config = {   

   capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        shardTestFiles: false,
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
    'binary': "<your_path>/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
  }
    },
```